# How to change the distance of components so that they do not overlap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change the distance of the components (textfield and button) so that they do not overlap but there is a space between them and I do not know how to do this.

I would like to at least add 1-2 spaces between the fieldtext and the button

Here's how it looks:

[image]

code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { Box, Paper, Button} from '@mui/material';

export default function Student() {
    const paperStyle={padding:'50px 20px', width:600, margin:"20px auto"}
    const[name, setName]=React.useState('')
    const[address, setAddress]=React.useState('')
  return (
    <Box
    
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
                <Paper elevation={3} style={paperStyle}>
                    <h1 style={{color:"blue"}}><u>text</u></h1>
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Name" variant="outlined" fullWidth 
      value={name}
      onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Address" variant="outlined" fullWidth
        value={address}
        onChange={(e)=>setAddress(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Button variant="outlined">Primary</Button>
      {name}
      {address}
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems like you'd simply add some margin with CSS or a library class.

Comment: By the way, It's invalid to have more than one element with the same ID.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I see two instances of `id="outlined-basic"` up there. Assuming both those elements are rendered, that's not allowed in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that `sx` prop on your `Box` would add the margin between the elements:

```
sx={{
  "& > :not(style)": { m: 1 }
}}
```

but the `>` limits it to only form elements directly inside the `Box` but because you added the `Paper` the css selector does not catch anymore.

the easyest thing would be to just more that `sx` prop from the `Box` to the `Paper`

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-rubin-80o3d2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `style={{ bottomGap: 10 }}` to both TextField components?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).